# Ordered list in 3 level

Tags: html, html-lists

I would like to have the ordered list as image below. (in html format)

[image: Please refer to this link for the image]

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using nested ul-li.

```
   <ul>
  <li>Item 1
      <ul>
    <li>
      Item 1.1
       <ul>
        <li>Item a </li>
        <li>Item b</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Item 1.2</li>

     <li> Item 1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> Item 2
    <ul>
    <li>
      Item 2.1
       <ul>
        <li>Item a </li>
        <li>Item b</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Item 2.2</li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Possible

There are many ways but one of my tricks was to create it in MS Word and save as HTML document. the code can be messy but it works

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    <!--
    /* Font Definitions */
    
    @font-face {
      font-family: Vrinda;
      panose-1: 2 11 5 2 4 2 4 2 2 3;
      mso-font-charset: 0;
      mso-generic-font-family: swiss;
      mso-font-pitch: variable;
      mso-font-signature: 65539 0 0 0 1 0;
    }
    
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Cambria Math";
      panose-1: 2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;
      mso-font-charset: 0;
      mso-generic-font-family: roman;
      mso-font-pitch: variable;
      mso-font-signature: -536870145 1107305727 0 0 415 0;
    }
    
    @font-face {
      font-family: Calibri;
      panose-1: 2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
      mso-font-charset: 0;
      mso-generic-font-family: swiss;
      mso-font-pitch: variable;
      mso-font-signature: -520092929 1073786111 9 0 415 0;
    }
    /* Style Definitions */
    
    p.MsoNormal,
    li.MsoNormal,
    div.MsoNormal {
      mso-style-unhide: no;
      mso-style-qformat: yes;
      mso-style-parent: "";
      margin-top: 0in;
      margin-right: 0in;
      margin-bottom: 10.0pt;
      margin-left: 0in;
      line-height: 115%;
      mso-pagination: widow-orphan;
      font-size: 11.0pt;
      font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
      mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-bidi-font-family: Vrinda;
      mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;
      mso-bidi-language: AR-SA;
    }
    
    p.MsoListParagraph,
    li.MsoListParagraph,
    div.MsoListParagraph {
      mso-style-priority: 34;
      mso-style-unhide: no;
      mso-style-qformat: yes;
      margin-top: 0in;
      margin-right: 0in;
      margin-bottom: 10.0pt;
      margin-left: .5in;
      mso-add-space: auto;
      line-height: 115%;
      mso-pagination: widow-orphan;
      font-size: 11.0pt;
      font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
      mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-bidi-font-family: Vrinda;
      mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;
      mso-bidi-language: AR-SA;
    }
    
    p.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst,
    li.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst,
    div.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst {
      mso-style-priority: 34;
      mso-style-unhide: no;
      mso-style-qformat: yes;
      mso-style-type: export-only;
      margin-top: 0in;
      margin-right: 0in;
      margin-bottom: 0in;
      margin-left: .5in;
      margin-bottom: .0001pt;
      mso-add-space: auto;
      line-height: 115%;
      mso-pagination: widow-orphan;
      font-size: 11.0pt;
      font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
      mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-bidi-font-family: Vrinda;
      mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;
      mso-bidi-language: AR-SA;
    }
    
    p.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle,
    li.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle,
    div.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle {
      mso-style-priority: 34;
      mso-style-unhide: no;
      mso-style-qformat: yes;
      mso-style-type: export-only;
      margin-top: 0in;
      margin-right: 0in;
      margin-bottom: 0in;
      margin-left: .5in;
      margin-bottom: .0001pt;
      mso-add-space: auto;
      line-height: 115%;
      mso-pagination: widow-orphan;
      font-size: 11.0pt;
      font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
      mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-bidi-font-family: Vrinda;
      mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;
      mso-bidi-language: AR-SA;
    }
    
    p.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast,
    li.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast,
    div.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast {
      mso-style-priority: 34;
      mso-style-unhide: no;
      mso-style-qformat: yes;
      mso-style-type: export-only;
      margin-top: 0in;
      margin-right: 0in;
      margin-bottom: 10.0pt;
      margin-left: .5in;
      mso-add-space: auto;
      line-height: 115%;
      mso-pagination: widow-orphan;
      font-size: 11.0pt;
      font-family: "Calibri", "sans-serif";
      mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-bidi-font-family: Vrinda;
      mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;
      mso-bidi-language: AR-SA;
    }
    
    .MsoChpDefault {
      mso-style-type: export-only;
      mso-default-props: yes;
      mso-bidi-font-size: 11.0pt;
      mso-ascii-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-ascii-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-fareast-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-fareast-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-hansi-font-family: Calibri;
      mso-hansi-theme-font: minor-latin;
      mso-bidi-font-family: Vrinda;
      mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-bidi;
      mso-bidi-language: AR-SA;
    }
    
    .MsoPapDefault {
      mso-style-type: export-only;
      margin-bottom: 10.0pt;
      line-height: 115%;
    }
    
    @page Section1 {
      size: 8.5in 11.0in;
      margin: 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;
      mso-header-margin: .5in;
      mso-footer-margin: .5in;
      mso-paper-source: 0;
    }
    
    div.Section1 {
      page: Section1;
    }
    /* List Definitions */
    
    @list l0 {
      mso-list-id: 310909608;
      mso-list-template-ids: 67698719;
    }
    
    @list l0:level1 {
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      text-indent: -.25in;
    }
    
    @list l0:level2 {
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: .55in;
      text-indent: -.3in;
    }
    
    @list l0:level3 {
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: .85in;
      text-indent: -.35in;
    }
    
    @list l0:level4 {
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 1.2in;
      text-indent: -.45in;
    }
    
    @list l0:level5 {
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.%5\.";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 1.55in;
      text-indent: -.55in;
    }
    
    @list l0:level6 {
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.%5\.%6\.";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 1.9in;
      text-indent: -.65in;
    }
    
    @list l0:level7 {
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.%5\.%6\.%7\.";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 2.25in;
      text-indent: -.75in;
    }
    
    @list l0:level8 {
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.%5\.%6\.%7\.%8\.";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 2.6in;
      text-indent: -.85in;
    }
    
    @list l0:level9 {
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.%5\.%6\.%7\.%8\.%9\.";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 3.0in;
      text-indent: -1.0in;
    }
    
    @list l1 {
      mso-list-id: 855194394;
      mso-list-type: hybrid;
      mso-list-template-ids: 419310286 67698711 67698713 67698715 67698703 67698713 67698715 67698703 67698713 67698715;
    }
    
    @list l1:level1 {
      mso-level-number-format: alpha-lower;
      mso-level-text: "%1\)";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 1.05in;
      text-indent: -.25in;
    }
    
    @list l2 {
      mso-list-id: 1075712010;
      mso-list-template-ids: -1556055096;
    }
    
    @list l2:level1 {
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      text-indent: -.25in;
    }
    
    @list l2:level2 {
      mso-level-legal-format: yes;
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: .75in;
      text-indent: -.25in;
    }
    
    @list l2:level3 {
      mso-level-legal-format: yes;
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 1.25in;
      text-indent: -.5in;
    }
    
    @list l2:level4 {
      mso-level-legal-format: yes;
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 1.5in;
      text-indent: -.5in;
    }
    
    @list l2:level5 {
      mso-level-legal-format: yes;
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.%5";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 2.0in;
      text-indent: -.75in;
    }
    
    @list l2:level6 {
      mso-level-legal-format: yes;
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.%5\.%6";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 2.25in;
      text-indent: -.75in;
    }
    
    @list l2:level7 {
      mso-level-legal-format: yes;
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.%5\.%6\.%7";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 2.75in;
      text-indent: -1.0in;
    }
    
    @list l2:level8 {
      mso-level-legal-format: yes;
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.%5\.%6\.%7\.%8";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 3.0in;
      text-indent: -1.0in;
    }
    
    @list l2:level9 {
      mso-level-legal-format: yes;
      mso-level-text: "%1\.%2\.%3\.%4\.%5\.%6\.%7\.%8\.%9";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 3.25in;
      text-indent: -1.0in;
    }
    
    @list l3 {
      mso-list-id: 1490708345;
      mso-list-type: hybrid;
      mso-list-template-ids: -1072021458 67698711 67698713 67698715 67698703 67698713 67698715 67698703 67698713 67698715;
    }
    
    @list l3:level1 {
      mso-level-number-format: alpha-lower;
      mso-level-text: "%1\)";
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: 1.05in;
      text-indent: -.25in;
    }
    
    @list l4 {
      mso-list-id: 1829009243;
      mso-list-type: hybrid;
      mso-list-template-ids: 1966236548 67698703 67698713 67698715 67698703 67698713 67698715 67698703 67698713 67698715;
    }
    
    @list l4:level1 {
      mso-level-tab-stop: none;
      mso-level-number-position: left;
      margin-left: .75in;
      text-indent: -.25in;
    }
    
    ol {
      margin-bottom: 0in;
    }
    
    ul {
      margin-bottom: 0in;
    }
    
    -->
  </style>
  <!--[if gte mso 10]>
<style>
 /* Style Definitions */
 table.MsoNormalTable
 {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
 mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
 mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
 mso-style-noshow:yes;
 mso-style-priority:99;
 mso-style-qformat:yes;
 mso-style-parent:"";
 mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
 mso-para-margin-top:0in;
 mso-para-margin-right:0in;
 mso-para-margin-bottom:10.0pt;
 mso-para-margin-left:0in;
 line-height:115%;
 mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
 mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
 mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
 mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
 mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
 mso-bidi-font-family:Vrinda;
 mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;
 mso-bidi-language:AR-SA;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="2050"/>
</xml><![endif]-->
  <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
  <o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1"/>
 </o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>

<body lang="EN-US" style="tab-interval:.5in">

  <div class="Section1">

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst" style="text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l2 level1 lfo1">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">1.<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item 1</p>

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle" style="margin-left:.55in;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.3in;mso-list:l0 level2 lfo2">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">1.1.<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item 1.1</p>

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle" style="margin-left:1.05in;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l3 level1 lfo3">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">a)<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item a</p>

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle" style="margin-left:1.05in;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l3 level1 lfo3">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">b)<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item b</p>

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle" style="margin-left:.55in;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.3in;mso-list:l0 level2 lfo2">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">1.2.<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item 1.2</p>

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle" style="margin-left:.55in;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.3in;mso-list:l0 level2 lfo2">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">1.3.<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item 1.3</p>

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle" style="text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo2">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">2.<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item 2</p>

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle" style="margin-left:.55in;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.3in;mso-list:l0 level2 lfo2">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">2.1.<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item 2.1</p>

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle" style="margin-left:1.05in;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l1 level1 lfo5">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">a)<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item a</p>

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle" style="margin-left:1.05in;mso-add-space:
auto;text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l1 level1 lfo5">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">b)<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item b</p>

    <p class="MsoListParagraphCxSpLast" style="margin-left:.55in;mso-add-space:auto;
text-indent:-.3in;mso-list:l0 level2 lfo2">
      <!--[if !supportLists]--><span style="mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-latin"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">2.2.<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span>
      </span>
      <!--[endif]-->Item 2.2</p>

  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you'd have to define special class for ordered list and define CSS for it, like this (put this entire row in `<head>` element):

```css
ol.sublist {
    counter-reset: item
}

ol.sublist > li {
    display: block
}

ol.sublist > li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol class="sublist">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <ol class="sublist">
        <li>Item 1.1</li>
        <li>Item 1.2</li>
        <ol type="a">
            <li>Item (a)</li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
</ol>
```